# What does "reporting lapses" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "While the German lender was fined 300,000 rubles for reporting lapses related to the money-laundering case, it’s still under investigation in London and New York." ([source](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-07-15/the-latest-weapon-russia-is-wielding-to-punish-its-wayward-banks))

What does **"reporting lapses"** mean in this sentence?

Comment: In context, it should be fairly obvious *reporting lapses* means *lapses* (errors, failures, shortcoming) within *the process of reporting*. But when parsing constructions of the general form *X was punished for [verbing]* we naturally start by assuming that *verbing* represents the punishable act itself. When it turns out to actually be an adjectival gerund noun (modifying *lapses*, in this case), the reader has to backtrack and reparse. So I would say this is a "garden path sentence", and the usage should be avoided as being unnecessarily awkward / obscure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Reporting lapses" means failing to report.

> (Bloomberg) -- Fiat Chrysler Automobiles NV will pay a $70 million fine for failing to report fatalities, injuries and warranty repairs as U.S. safety regulators step up their enforcement **in the wake of lapses** by automakers in making required disclosures. ([Source](http://www.garp.org/#!/risk-intelligence/detail/a1Z400000031TpcEAE))

Comment: I wonder how something which is absent produces a wake. :)